# What is considered "reasonable expenses" for reimbursement when Ryanair cancels a flight?

Tags: compensation, ryanair

Ryanair cancelled a flight on a lightly scheduled route from Brussels, Belgium to Nantes, France and could not get my family on another Ryanair flight until 2 days later. I was told by the chat agent that I could submit my meal and accommodation expenses for reimbursement, but without any qualification of what reasonable meant. Nor does their own website offer guidance: https://www.ryanair.com/content/dam/ryanair/help-centre-pdfs/eu261-notices-v15/EU261%20for%20United%20Kingdom%20-%20EN.pdf

I feel my family stayed well within reasonable, but now Ryanair says that they will reimburse only €25 per person per day. To eat 3 healthy meals out at restaurants for €25 per day in Brussels seems very *unreasonable*.  One could barely get 3 complete meals at fast food restaurants for that amount.

What have others experienced, both as your per day cost to eat out for 3 meals in a comparable city and what you've been reimbursed?

Comment: Is it really that difficult to eat out in Brussels for 25€/day? Web sites I have found, which estimate travel expenses in Brussels are not far away in their estimates when describing budget travelling. Checking the menu at a few cafés and restaurants seem to indicate that the prices are similar to here in Munich, where I live, and I would have no problem here to get healthy and decent 'food on the go' for 25€/day if I had to.

Comment: What did you actually spend?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo On the other hand, the US Government's [per-diem meals rate for Brussels](https://aoprals.state.gov/web920/per_diem_action.asp?MenuHide=1&PostCode=10111) (not technically binding on others, but a somewhat de-facto standard in the US) is $134/day off-peak and $145/day peak.

Comment: A possible rule of thumb for ‘reasonable’ might be a) the daily amount you typically spend on food; b) the cost of a light breakfast pastries/baked goods, fruits, toast, coffee, a takeaway sandwich & drink lunch, a one course evening meal. It’s probably not ‘reasonable’ to expect expenses to cover 3 full meals a day in restaurants, or include alcoholic drinks, for example. As a comparison, the BA website says ‘we won’t reimburse any unreasonable expenses’ but doesn’t define further, while Citizens Advice says ‘…you are unlikely to get money back for alcohol, expensive meals or luxury hotels’

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Something being possible is not the same as being practical. Yes, I believe I _could_ eat out in Brussels for that amount however, had they stipulated that, I would have more likely insisted they get me to my destination sooner. Two things to point out here; 1) they never communicated expectations ahead of time, and 2) not every traveller is a budget traveller on a backpacking trip.

Comment: @Traveller here is a breakfast from one morning.  While lunch was similar, dinner was of course, higher.  I concede alcohol need not be included, but judging from diners I typically see around me, having an alcoholic drink with dinner is more the norm than the exception and therefore would be consider reasonable by most.

1 Berry Pancake 15.00
1 French toast 14.00
1 Junior pancake 9.50
1 Pancake 14.50
1 Mushroom omelette 16.50
4 Latte Macchiato 16.00
3 orange juice 15.00
total 100.50...divided by 5 = 20.10 just for breakfast

Comment: And exactly because you could eat out for that amount, that is what airlines consider reasonable. The intention behind the compensation is that you should not starve while waiting for your new departure. The compensation is not supposed to finance a continued high-class holiday. The prices you quote must be from a rather expensive restaurant. At Tonton Garby (rated 4,8 on Google Maps and clearly a decent place) you could have had a baguette with cheese, tomato and salad and a fresh orange juice for 5,50€. That is likely a comparable amount of food as the french toast and juice you paid 20€ for